# powershell write txt file many times

Tags: powershell

```
$sentFilePath = Join-Path -Path $localPath -ChildPath $sentFile -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if (Test-Path -Path $sentFilePath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
    $sentFiles = Get-Content -Path $sentFilePath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
else {
    $sentFiles = @()
}

$localName = $localFile.Name
        $localSize = $localFile.Length
        $localDate = $localFile.LastWriteTime.ToString()

$isSent = $false
        foreach ($sentFile in $sentFiles) {

if ($sentFile -eq "$localName,$localSize,$localDate") {
                $isSent = $true
                break

$sentFiles += "$localName,$localSize,$localDate"

"$localName,$localSize,$localDate" | Out-File -FilePath "C:\links\sentFiles.txt" -Append -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Above is a snippet of a few fragments that I'm not sure what causes the error.

I want to save information about a file sent to FTP only once to a text file called "sentFiles.txt". Files are sent to the server FTP correctly, but information about the sent files is written repeatedly for the same files to the sentFiles.txt file and it is issue.

I tried several code changes, but to no avail. I don't know how to change it

Comment: Please post complete and syntactically valid code - not "snippets of fragments"